# Why is usleep not working at boot time?

Tags: macos, delay, sleep, boot, launchd

I have a daemon that `launchd` runs at system boot (OS X).  I need to delay startup of my daemon by 3-5 seconds, yet the following code executes instantly at boot, but delays properly well after boot:

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
printf("Before delay\n");
unsigned int delay = 3000000;
while( (delay=usleep(delay)) > 0)
{
   ;
}
printf("After delay\n");
```

If I run it by hand after the system has started, it delays correctly.  If I let `launchd` start it at boot the console log shows that there is no delay between Before delay and After delay - they are executed in the same second.

If I could get `launchd` to execute my daemon after a delay after boot that would be fine as well, but my reading suggests that this isn't possible (perhaps I'm wrong?).

Otherwise, I need to understand why usleep isn't working, and what I can do to fix it, or what delay I might be able to use instead that works that early in the boot process.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by delaying your code execution?

Comment: @Costique I'm waiting for various services to not only become available, but to have performed some specific actions which I cannot test for.  Further this daemon has to run on tiger through snow leopard and the services are slightly different in each case - I want to avoid adding additional code to check for the platform.  A simple delay may be considered a hack, but it's an elegant one in that it would solve my problems on all platforms without affecting the overall operation of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first. Put in some extra *code* to also print out the current time, rather than relying on `launchd` to do it.

It's possible that the different flushing behaviour for standard output may be coming into play.

If standard output can be determined to be an interactive device (such as running it from the command line), it is *line* buffered - you'll get the "before" line flushed before the delay.

Otherwise, it's fully buffered so the flush may not happen until the program exits (or you reach the buffer size of (for example) 4K. That means that `launchd` may see the lines come out together, both *after* the delay.

Getting the C code to timestamp the lines will tell you if ths is the problems, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("%d: Before delay\n", time(0));
    unsigned int delay = 3000000;
    while( (delay=usleep(delay)) > 0);
    printf("%d: After delay\n", time(0));

    return 0;
}
```

To see why the buffering may be a problem, consider running that program above as follows:

```
pax> ./testprog | while read; do echo $(date): $REPLY; done
Tue Jan 31 12:59:24 WAST 2012: 1327985961: Before delay
Tue Jan 31 12:59:24 WAST 2012: 1327985964: After delay
```

You can see that, because the buffering causes both lines to appear to the `while` loop when the program *exits,* they get the same timestamp of `12:59:24` despite the fact they were generated three seconds apart within the program.

In fact, if you change it as follows:

```
pax> ./testprog | while read; do echo $(date) $REPLY; sleep 10 ; done
Tue Jan 31 13:03:17 WAST 2012 1327986194: Before delay
Tue Jan 31 13:03:27 WAST 2012 1327986197: After delay
```

you can see the time seen by the "surrounding" program (the `while` loop or, in your case, `launchd`) is totally disconnected from the program itself).

Secondly, `usleep` is a function that can *fail!* And it can fail by returning -1, which is very much not greater than zero.

That means, if it fails, your delay will be effectively nothing.

The [Single UNIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/usleep.html) states, for `usleep`:

> On successful completion, usleep() returns 0. Otherwise, it returns -1 and sets errno to indicate the error.
>
> The usleep() function may fail if: [EINVAL]: The time interval specified 1,000,000 or more microseconds.

That's certainly the case with your code although it would be hard to explain why it works *after* boot and not before.

Interestingly, the Mac OSX docs don't list EINVAL but they *do* allow for EINTR if the sleep is interrupted externally. So again, something you should check.

You can check those possibilities with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("%d: Before delay\n", time(0));
    unsigned int delay = 3000000;
    while( (delay=usleep(delay)) > 0);
    printf("%d: After delay\n", time(0));
    printf("Delay became %d, errno is %d\n", delay, errno);
}
```

---

One other thing I've just noticed, from your code you seem to be assuming that `usleep` returns the number of microseconds unslept (remaining) and you loop until it's all done, but that behaviour is not borne out by the man pages.

I know that `nanosleep` does this (by updating the passed structure to contain the remaining time rather than returning it) but `usleep` only returns 0 or -1.

The `sleep` function acts in that manner, returning the number of seconds yet to go. Perhaps you might look into using that function instead, if possible.

In any case, I would still run that (last) code segment above just so you can ascertain *what* the actual problem is.

Comment: Great point, however it's obvious in this case - I added a 60 second delay to test it out, and the application was certainly operating fully well before 60 seconds after power-up.

Comment: @Adam, you should _still_ get the time from the C runtime to confirm it, then post the results of that. In addition, I've added the possibility that usleep is allowed to fail, something else you should check.

Comment: It turns out that in addition to using usleep incorrectly there were buffering issues and another issue that was unrelated, but found to be affecting how the delay progressed.  Thanks for your input - you get the selected answer as, of course, additional debugging output pushed me to the correct solution after all.

Answer (score 1):

According to the old POSIX.1 standard, and as documented in the [OSX manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/usleep.3.html), `usleep` returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

If you get an error it's most likely `EINTR` (the only error documented in the OSX manual page) meaning it has been interrupted by a signal. You better check `errno` to be certain though. As a side-note, on the [Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) it states that you can get `EINVAL` too in some cases:

> usec is not smaller than 1000000. (On systems where that is considered an error.)

As another side-note, `usleep` has been obseleted in the latest POSIX.1 standard, in favor of `nanosleep`.